# How to sum two column & save in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datagridview

I have a table in database with three columns, there's a Grid associated with my database, I want to sum  the first two columns and display the total in third column and also save the total sum in database. How can I do that? If you could please provide me with an example.

Comment: Basically you need to set up a connection to your database and then write the values from your gridview into the correct table... but please show us what you have tried and where you ran into problems.

Comment: you want to save gridview data to db so from where you are getting data for gridview first?

Comment: Please add your  sample code

Comment: [what about this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/sum-of-columns-of-two-tables-into-one-column-in-sql-server-2/)

Comment: I suggest you also read about `Database Normalization`. Seeing what you want to achieve you most likely don't know about these standard yet. It's a very good thing to know when working with relationship first generation database system.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the following query to show the result

```
select first_column,second_column,first_column+second_column from yourTable
```